# Warten bis oder auf?

Tags: preposition

How does one decide whether to use bis or auf with warten? For instance, which is correct in this sentence:

> Sie wartete **auf** einen günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung.

> Sie wartete **bis** einen günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is correct. The second one would need to be:

> Sie wartete bis zum günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung.

There is a very subtle difference in meaning. I believe in English I would translate:

> Sie wartete auf ...
>
> She was waiting for ...

> Sie wartete bis (zu) ...
>
> She waited until ...

But I'm not 100 % sure about the English tenses (because there isn't much context in your example).

Comment: Both the tenses would be correct for either phrase in English, it would depend on whether the waiting is "complete" at the time. The main point is *warten auf* = "to wait for (a person/thing)" and *warten bis* = "to wait until (an event)".

Comment: Yes, I know. In OP's example I would choose the tenses as given in my answer but it is a bit difficult to decide without additional context.