# "Warten bis" oder "warten bis zu"?

Tags: preposition

[In another question the following sentence was corrected](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70890/warten-bis-oder-auf):

> Sie wartete **bis** einen günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung.

to this:

> Sie wartete **bis zum** günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung.

However, [DWDS.de says that the "zu" is not always necessary](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=warten%20bis&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=100). For instance:

> Ich wartete bis Ende Oktober. #11

> Wir warteten bis Montag, dann fuhren Frau Ubben u. Kreuzig nach Allrode. #12

> Er wartete bis 10 Uhr. #37

> Sie und Cornelius Friebott warteten bis elf Uhr abends zusammen im lichtlosen Zimmer, ob der Feind käme. #45

How does the first sentence differ from these such that a "zu" is required?

Comment: The accepted answer answers your question, but your second example is very undiomatic. In this case, you would use »warten auf« which can be followed directly by a noun; I'd say »Sie wartete auf einen günstigen Moment ...«.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage note in the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bis#Preposition) explains this. Basically, *bis* is not a 'normal' preposition since it's not followed by a noun except in certain cases. In the temporal sense it can be used with a specific time or date you can point to on a clock or calendar. So *bis Montag*, *bis 2 Uhr*, *bis nächste Woche*, etc. are okay, but with other nouns you have to insert another preposition such as *zu*. For example, it's common to hear *bis zum nächsten Mal* = "until next time" at the end of radio and television shows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is was a wrong correction given.

Sie wartete bis einen günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung.

to this:

Sie wartete bis zum günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung.

Richtig wäre: Sie **wartete** *einen* günstigen Moment der elterlichen Ablenkung **ab**.

Comment: Yes, but that is about »abwarten«, the question asks about »warten«.

Comment: Although I had asked about warten, the insightful correction is additionally helpful to my translating, and I am grateful for it. I learned something I did not expect to learn. A bonus.